# Updating packages on a CentOS 5.5 VPS

Tags: centos, vps, yum, update

I have been running a VPS for several weeks now and yum has informed me that 67 package updates are available. I'm very new to Linux and server administration in general. I have taken time to configure Apache, PHP and a few other necessary programs for security and to customize. If an update is available and I choose to install it, will this overwrite any changes I have made to the config? For example if I update PHP will php.ini be overwritten and returned to its default state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an RPM needs to modify a config file, generally it is updated by a script rather than a drop-in replacement. For major packages like Apache, PHP, and MySQL they're very careful about that. It is safe to apply the updates.